# Specifying column types from external file for read_csv

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe (649 columns) from a survey with many NA, leading sometimes to wrong automatic column type.

I have created a csv file to assign each column name to a column type. I imported it as "question type" and transformed in a vector using
`question_types =read_csv2("Type of question.csv") %>% select("col_types_r") %>% pull`

I want to use it in the col_type argument of the `readr :: read_csv()` function.

question_type is a vector of character lenght 649 composed of "c", "d" and "?"

```
summary(question_types)
   Length     Class      Mode 
      649 character character
```

When importing the csv while specifying the col_type I have this warning "Unnamed `col_types` should have the same length as `col_names`. Using smaller of the two" and only the first column is imported.

I don't understand why because the vector has the same length as the number of columns of df.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it somehow possible to make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? It's hard to give an answer without knowing the data.

Comment: Reproducible example is hard to do but I can put an extract from the file. How could I import it?

Comment: Perhaps you can show the first 10 colums and rows. Use `dput(YOURDATA[1:10, 1:10])` (or something like that) and put the `structure`-output into your question (use the Edit-Button). The same for your `question_type`-vector and you should show the code, you used which failed.